# Delete first word of each line

Tags: vim

How do I delete first word of each line in Vim?

How about a pattern on each line?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would use something like the following:

```
:%s/^\w+\s+//
```

The regular expression will match one or more "word" characters starting at the beginning of the line followed by at least one whitespace character.  It will remove the word and any following whitespace.  If a line can contain only a single word -- and you still want it removed -- you could use alternation to match either whitespace or the end of line.

```
:%s/^\w+(\s+|$)//
```

Comment: You can express this more generally:

:%:s/^\\(\w\{-1,}\\)\\(\W\?\\)/\2/

This way you also don't throw away whatever terminates the word character.

(You also need to watch which dialect of regexp you're speaking...)

Answer (score 46):

:normal to the rescue:

```
:%norm dw
```

It basically replays the arguments as if you were typing them in normal ('non-edit') mode.

**From :help :**

:norm[al][!] {commands}

Execute Normal mode commands {commands}.

This makes it possible to execute Normal mode commands typed on the
command-line.  {commands} is executed like it is typed.

Comment: If you ran `:norm dw` on a line that was indented, it would delete the indentation instead of the first word. Running `:norm ^dw` would always delete the first word.

Answer (score 31):

Going for cryptic here, in true vi style:

```
1Gq10dwjq100000@1
```

Randy fixed this up in the comments to work on more than 100000 lines:

```
ggqqdwj@qq@q
```

For those starting out with Vim, this breaks down to:

```
gg    - Go to first line
qq    - Record a macro into register 'q'
dwj@q - The macro:
            dw - delete word at cursor
            j  - go down one line
            @q - run the macro in register 'q'
q     - Stop recording the macro
@q    - Execute the macro in register 'q'
```

In essence, the macro is recursive - it deletes a word, moves down a line, then calls itself again, repeating for each line until end of file. The final '@q' is the initial (manual) call needed to set the macro off on every line.

Comment: -1 - not sure what's "true vi style", but there is no point in doing cryptic, unfriendly things, just to show off. there is perfectly readable solution, which is also more general.

Comment: Ah, but someone's already posted the 'correct' solution. This was more along the lines of code golf.

The "true vi style" was an ironical swipe at an editor where :wq! is the correct way to exit without changes. It's not the most user-friendly beast. Full disclosure: I love vi and use it as my main editor. Full disclosure: vi command syntax is not very understandable.

Comment: ggqqdwj@qq@q will work on any number of lines, not just files with lines < 100000.  Tbh, this 'cryptic' was was what came first in my mind over a regular expression.

Comment: I work with tab-delimited data where each file has over 20 000 000 lines (over 2.1 Gb as plain text). Native commands such as this one are still very useful.

Comment: Randys comment is the best answer IMHO. The question was how to do it in vi, not with sed.

Comment: This only works when the word starts the line.  If there's whitespace before the first word, you just eat the whitespace.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething, de instead of dw? or dE?

Comment: @AlexFeinman All I know is that this has shown me, after 15+ years of using vi, I've barely scratched the surface...

Comment: Very clever... I did not realize macros allowed recursion.

Comment: The second command doesn't work if there are two whitespaces after the first word. In that case, it removes the second word as well

Comment: A revelation to me.  I'm going to try to do everything using vi macros from now on!

Answer (score 4):

First word (where word is defined as no whitespace)

```
:%s/^\s*[^ ]* //g
```

Delete pattern:

```
:%s/< insert pattern here >//g
```

Answer (score 4):

What about this?
:%!cut -s -d' ' -f2-

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s,^[^ ]*,,
```

From the beginning of the line match anything, but not a space and replace with none.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this won't delete anything on lines with indentation, and that this deletes what Vim calls WORDS (separated with whitespace), not words.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, if someone else is looking to do this you could do use visual block.

> - press ctrl+v
> - select all the lines you would want to edit
> - now use arrow keys to select the entire word
> - press 'x'

That would delete the first word in all the lines. This method is especially very handy to edit log files